# Can't telnet Apache2 Web Server from WAN on port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, port, telnet

Is there specific port configuration to httpd.conf that opens port 80 aside from using `Listen 80` directive?

netstat -aon gives LISTENING but I cannot `telnet machineName 80` (says failed to connect)

PS: Firewall rules has been set for port 80 but still no success any ideas?

Comment: Does it work on the same machine? If so Apache's configured correctly.

Comment: same machine yes, even within the network (the LAN) but outside no

Comment: Ok. So then something is wrong with that configuration. You don't tell us anything about it, so we can only guess, and my guess is that you're behind NAT and port forwarding is not configured.

Comment: so only admin could do the job of changing some rules at the router ?

Comment: Effectively, yes.

Answer (score 0):

So let's do this in steps.

First, on machineName. If you can `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` and get a response, your Apache is configured properly; if you can `telnet machineName 80` from that machine, it's also listening on its external net and the firewall is set properly. If it's not listening on the external port, you may need to set `listen *:80`.

Now. On another machine on your in-house network. From there try `telnet machineName 80`. If that works, your in-house DNS is handling the machine name properly.

Finally, from outside. First, you have to define a name for your machine. Option 1, you already own a domain, you have to set an A record for the machine in that domain, which indicates that `machineName.yourdomain.com` is active at your WAN address. Option 2, you buy a domain and point an A record at your WAN address. Option 3, you buy and set up a dynamic DNS on your router. In any case, you then have to have sufficient permissions on your router to set up a "port forward" on port 80 that directs traffic arriving at your WAN to the internal address of `machineName`. Only then can you connect from outside, by either (e.g.) `telnet myMachine.yourdomain.con 80` or simply pointing a web browser at it by name.

Comment: listen *:80 doesn't work. machineName.yourdomain.com is actually active at WAN, but with port 80 closed I can't access the proxy URL

Comment: ALL is ok except that port 80 along with any other port except 8080 (as far as I tried) are closed, how to open them in WAN .

Comment: As Vidarlo points out, you need a port forward set through your router. Whoever is in charge of your router needs to (1) set a DHCP reservation for your machine so its address in-house stays constant, and (2) set a port forward on port 80 (and preferably 443 for https) that forwards traffic on those ports to your machine.

Comment: ok but why port 8080 is working? did they do port forwarding for it and not for port 80?

Comment: Clearly they must have... is port 8080 pointed to your machine? is there something on your machine answering to port 8080? or perhaps they've set a port forward that accepts port 8080 traffic and redirects it to port 80 on your machine. 8080 is a common port for private or test web sites.